# Cache space taken is becoming huge - is it Google maps 2.0 auto caching effect?

Tags: android, caching, google-maps-android-api-2

I notice that my application cache was starting to take a lot of cache space (up to 15 MB) from an application taking 12 MB space. At first I was very worried about fundamental flaw in my work.

But I notice that other applications using Maps 2.0 and especially GoogleMaps Application were also having large caching. I also know that one nice feature of the Maps API 2.0 was auto caching. So:

**is it the new maps Api that is causing that huge cache values?**

Or do I have to **search for flaws/memory leaks**?

To give an idea, GoogleMaps is requiring 11.62 MB of space for the application but has **285 MB** space taken by its cache !! (I love to look & use maps a lot from navigating to zooming to 3D buildings representation so that might explain the cache size)

Anyone?